# How to find the smallest positive integer value of n when n is described as an interval, in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So, my calculation gives me the following output:

`n \[Element] Integers &&(n<0 || n>=2)`

How do I parse\compute this in a way that yields me (in this case) 2, which I then can use in further calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the smallest so use Minimize with constraints on the solution.

```
Minimize[{n,n \[Element] Integers &&(n<0 || n>=2) && n>0},n]
```

which instantly returns

```
{2,{n->2}}
```